# Android Volley JsonArrayRequest send and get List<Object>

Tags: android, json, spring, spring-boot, android-volley

I want to send JsonArrayRequest with LinkedList as param and get same type as result. I get error 400 which means something wrong with my request:

```
        RequestQueue volleyQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        final Type type = new TypeToken<LinkedList<MyClass>>() {}.getType();
        LinkedList<MyClass> data = new LinkedList<>();
        //populate data...
        try {
            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(
                    Request.Method.GET,
                    BASE_URL,
                    new JSONArray(new Gson().toJson(data)),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            try {
                                processResultData((LinkedList<MyClass>) new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), type));
                            } catch (Exception e) {}
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }
            );
            request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(VOLLEY_TIME_OUT, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            volleyQueue.add(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
```

on the server side it's Java spring boot application which means:

```
@RestController
public class ApiClass {
    @RequestMapping("/base_url")
    public LinkedList<MyClass> foo(@RequestBody LinkedList<MyClass> data) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell us the Volley error message that you are getting in onErrorResponse. 400 means Bad request, that means the server is not expecting the request format (either header or body).

Comment: @MayurKaul "BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for <url>" that' all I have...